# Find the Expected Value of This Random Variable

Tags: probability

A company agrees to accept the highest of four sealed bids on a property. The
four bids are regarded as four independent random variables with common
cumulative distribution function:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
 \ \tfrac{1}{2}(1 + \sin \pi x) \ \ \ \ \ & \text{where } 3/2 \le x \le 5/2 \\
 \ 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Someone already helped me find the solution, but I don't see what I did wrong in my first attempt.  What I did was to set $B_1 \ldots B_4$ as the bids.  Then:
\begin{align}
Y \ \ & = \ \ \max \{ \, B_1 \ldots B_4 \, \} \\ \\
EY \ \ & = \ \ E(B_1 \, | \, B_1 \text{ highest})P(B_1 \text{ highest}) \ldots \\
& \ \ \ \ \ + E(B_4 \, | \, B_4 \text{ highest})P(B_4 \text{ highest}) \\
& = \ \ E(B_1)P(B_1 \text{ highest}) \ldots + E(B_4)P(B_4 \text{ highest}) \\
& = \ \ E(B_1) \cdot [ \, P(B_1 \text{ highest}) \ldots + P(B_4 \text{ highest}) \, ] \\
& = \ \ E(B_1) \ \ = \ \ 2
\end{align}
The correct solution is to view $P(Y \le x) = P(B_1 \ldots B_4 \le x) = P(B_1 \le x)^4$.  Then, find the density function and integrate.  For the record, $EY = 285/128$.

Comment: Why does $E(B_1\mid B_1~\text{highest})$ equal $E(B_1) = 2$? What you are claiming is that the highest bid has average value $2$ whereas it seems reasonable to assume that the highest bid would typically have value _more_ than $2$, which is the average value of the 4 bids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your steps are correct: it is valid to say that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \sum_{i=1}^4 \mathbb E[B_i \mid B_i \text{ highest}] \cdot \Pr[B_i \text{ highest}] \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^4 \mathbb E[B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}] \cdot \Pr[B_i \text{ highest}] & \text{(by symmetry)} \\
 &= \mathbb E[B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}] \sum_{i=1}^4 \Pr[B_i \text{ highest}] \\
 &= \mathbb E[B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}].
\end{align}

It is not correct to simplify $\mathbb E[B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}]$ to $\mathbb E[B_1]=2$. Intuitively, knowing that $B_1$ was larger than three other random variables makes it more likely to have large values, even if you don't care about what values the other random variables have.

You already have one approach to solving the problem. Another approach, from here, would be to figure out the density function of the conditional distribution $(B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest})$, by using Bayes's theorem:
$$f_{B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}}(x) = \frac{\Pr[B_1 \text{ highest} \mid B_1 = x] f_{B_1}(x)}{\Pr[B_1 \text{ highest}]} = \frac{\Pr[B_i\le x]^3 f_{B_1}(x)}{1/4} = 4 F(x)^3 f(x)$$ 
where $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \cos (\pi x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$. Then, you can compute the expected value by the usual computation
$$\mathbb E[B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}] = \int_{3/2}^{5/2} x f_{B_1 \mid B_1 \text{ highest}}(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: This may take a little time to sink in.  I did exactly as you described; since I don't care about the values in the other bids, $E(B_1 \, | \, B_1 \text{ highest}) = E(B_1)$.

Comment: If I told you that $B_1 = 1.51$ then it would be very unlikely to be the highest bid (since the bids are distributed between $1.5$ and $2.5$). So, conversely, if $B_1$ is the highest bid, it is very unlikely to be as low as $1.51$. Generalizing, we get the bias that makes $\mathbb E[B_1 \mid B_1\text{ highest}]$ bigger than the unconditional $\mathbb E[B_1]$.

Comment: I saw my mistake.  To rephrase formally what you all said, we have:  $E(B_1 \, | \, B_1 \text{ highest}) = E(B_1 \, | \, B_1 \ge b_2, b_3, b_4)$.  Clearly, the expected value of $B_1$ cannot be independent on the condition imposed on itself.